# How do i use force index with QueryDSL?

Tags: hibernate, querydsl, jpa-2.1

I'm currently working on project which uses queryDsl, jpa and hibernate with mysql as database. One of the generated queries took 625 seconds to execute. Since i do not have the freedom to change the indexes on the table itself but i can use force index on the actual query, which drops the query time to 0.62 seconds during testing, how do i do it in QueryDSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use force index directly in Querydsl JPA, since such syntax is not supported. It is possible to customize the Hibernate SQL rendering, but it is not trivial http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/10/07/using-use-index-with-hibernatemysql/

I'd recommend to use SQL in this case. You can use SQL with Querydsl JPA using `JPASQLQuery` and `HibernateSQLQuery`.